# Linq filter builder not accepting lambda for filter type IN

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq

Basically what I'm trying to do is a deleteMany based on a list of items that I have using C# and linq for a mongoDB.

This is my code:

```
// List of elements to delete, read from the POST request   
string jsonBoletines = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();

// Convert the JSON into a list of "Boletin" objects, which is the type of objects I want //to delete from the collection 
List <Boletin> boletinesToDelete = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Boletin>>(jsonBoletines);

// Create the filter using IN, I'm trying to delete using the _id
var filter = Builders<Boletin>.Filter.In(item => item._id, boletinesToDelete);

var results = collection.DeleteMany(filter);
```

My code will not compile because on the lambda inside the IN filter shows this error:

```
var filter = Builders<Boletin>.Filter.In(item => item._id, boletinesToDelete);
```

> CS1660: Cannot convert lambda expression to type X because it is not a delegate type

Did some research and the error is supposed to be "This error occurs if you try to assign or otherwise convert an anonymous method block to a type which is not a delegate type". But I'm not sure I get it since I'm not that familiar with delegate type

Please help

Answer (score 0):

From memory, I think an intersect may work better for this.

```
var filter =  Builders<Boletin>.Intersect(boletinesToDelete);
```

Comment: There is no intersect filter, the only one showing up is GeoIntersect

Comment: Can you switch them around, using:  var filter = boletines.Intersect(Builders<Boletin>); instead? I think the item that you call intersect on must be enumerable. Also, it may help to know what Builders<T> contains.

Comment: Thank you joshman1019, I managed to solve it in a different way, by removing the lambda and still using IN operator on the filter. I´ll post my solution in case someone else needs it

Answer (score 0):

`boletinesToDelete` should be a `List<ObjectId>` or a `List<string>` according to your `item._id` not a `List<Boletin>`.

```
db.collection.find({
  _id: {
    "$in": [
      ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
      ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001")
    ]
  }
})
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Fx2rtjdHuyP)

Comment: But why does it have to be a list of ObjectId? I could send only the list of IDs instead of the full objects, but I think that is the purpose of the lamda in the IN operator, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it´s the best way to solve it, but it´s the way it worked for me

```
// read the contents of the POST body data into a string
   string listBoletines = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            
// listBoletines is a list of string IDs, so need to convert to ObjectId
    
//Fist create an array with each ID
string [] boletinesToDelete = listBoletines.Split(',');

//Create a second array of type ObjectId 
ObjectId[] idsToDelete = new ObjectId[boletinesToDelete.Length];

//For each string on first array create it's corresponding ObjectId and insert on second array
for (int i=0; i<boletinesToDelete.Length; i++)
 {
    idsToDelete[i] = new ObjectId(boletinesToDelete[i]);
 }
 
//Finally I an use that in the filter against a MongoDB _id   
 var filter = Builders<Boletin>.Filter.In("_id", idsToDelete);
 var results = collection.DeleteMany(filter);
```